# Converting Bytes to float format

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, udp

I have the following data from a datagram message received by UDP socket:

```
b'/13/raw\x00,ffffffffffffff\x00=\xca\x00\x00=[\x00\x00\xbf\x82H\x00B\x14\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B;\x81\n\xbf\xbat4C-\xfd\xb0B\x87\xac\xd9\x00\x00\x00\x00E\xcd\xc0\x00I\xcc\xc1\xe0'
```

This is my code:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((IP, p))
print("Listening for UDP packets on {0}:{1} ...".format(IP, p))
while 1:
    rawdata, _ = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print(rawdata)
```

How can I convert rawdata to floats?

This is the data type that I am expecting:
[image]

Both are different samples!

Thank you

Comment: you need to know what the data represents and what you are expecting ... then you usually use something like struct.unpack

Comment: theres no way that data represnts what you put as expected

Comment: Thanks, I added that information. I am expecting floats @JoranBeasley

Comment: please dont use screenshots for text...

Comment: are you sure that expected data matches that specific bytestring or is it a generic expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each float is 4 bytes of data (typically... not always... again you need to consult the docs for whatever p[ayload you need)

but assuming that `/13/raw` is easy enough for you and the rest is what you need to decode

if we assume that `\x00` is some sort of delimiter we are left with the bytestring as follows

```
msgBytes = b',ffffffffffffff\x00=\xca\x00\x00=[\x00\x00\xbf\x82H\x00B\x14\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B;\x81\n\xbf\xbat4C-\xfd\xb0B\x87\xac\xd9\x00\x00\x00\x00E\xcd\xc0\x00I\xcc\xc1\xe0'
```

we can see there are 72 characters which means 18 floats (18*4 === 72)

*however your expected output only seems to have 14 floats* so that means 16 bytes are some sort of metadata (maybe a checksum, or some payload information (how many floats to expect))

we can just struct unpack it as floats now ... but i dont get your "expected value"
so some of those may be doubles or something other than 4 byte floats

`floats = struct.unpack('18f',msgBytes)`

now you have a list of 18 floats ... but again not matching your expected output, it may be related to endianness or some other method that you need to do additional processing on (eg maybe it should be ints and they become floats by dividing by 100 or something?)

[edit] investigating further I suspect `ffffffffff\x00` is some sort of header or metadata
so if we start with

```
myBytes = b'=\xca\x00\x00=[\x00\x00\xbf\x82H\x00B\x14\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B;\x81\n\xbf\xbat4C-\xfd\xb0B\x87\xac\xd9\x00\x00\x00\x00E\xcd\xc0\x00I\xcc\xc1\xe0'
```

and unpack it with `struct.unpack('14f',myBytes)` we get 14 floats as expected ... some are zero like in your example ... but the rest dont match

```
(7.254942539348875e-41, 3.273012823123475e-41, 6.659058584274783e-39, 1.1762210642058864e-38, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.244453845292514e-32, 2.2792208653754642e-07, -1.84210369180704e-09, -6070301691478016.0, 0.0, 1.7706052095336117e-38, -1.1171693447134314e+20)
```

so I think we still dont have enough info to actually answer this question, need to know more about the datasource and other stuff

Comment: if you take your example and `struct.unpack('>14f', myBytes)` you get floats in a range that more closely aligns with the original expected result.

Comment: yeah that seems closer :)